# Concatenate a string and a number in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a project in C# using SQL as backend.

I want to insert a code in SQL eg ABC001, where ABC comes from the COMPANY table and the `001` is done wrt to `emp_id` from `EMPLOYEE` table i.e. last `ID+1` but in the form of `001,002...999`.

How can I do the `ID+1` part of it?

Comment: We need more information than that, i.e. the relationships between the tables.

Comment: So, why do you want to construct a composite key and store it in one column? You could store this as separate CompanyID and emp_id columns, and not regret the decision later...

Comment: Hi, maybe I was not clear in what i want to do. Basically in the c# form, the output has to be ABC001 ie ABC from the company table and 001 from the employee table. What I need to Kw is how can I do 001, 002 ..... in the C# form.??? Sorry for the mistake..

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: @marc_s - looks like he does not want to use sql, just winforms.

Comment: Basically what i want to do is, 
1. extract the last ID, eg 1
2. add 1 to it, eg 2
3. get it in format 000, eg 002
4. concatenate it to ABC, ABC002 
all in a C# form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to Concatenate a string and a number in C# ?

```
string result = string.Format("{0}{1:000}", comp, emp_id+1);
```

or

```
string result = comp + (emp_id+1).ToString("000");
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. This violates normalization in a way that is generally unneeded. Instead, store both fields as individual columns and, if you are using this to provide a human-readable-identifier, use your mapping layer to query against the composite key rather than storing it.

The computation is cheap and the simplification of not building your own key generation function is a real win.

Comment: Hi, maybe I was not clear in what i want to do. Basically in the c# form, the output has to be ABC001 ie ABC from the company table and 001 from the employee table. What I need to Kw is how can I do 001, 002 ..... in the C# form.??? Sorry for the mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after.But if you are looking for updating some string from the format ABC001 to ABC002, ABC003,... etc, The below C# code will do it assuming you want to increase the number part which is the last 3 characters of the original string. (you mentioned 0 to 999)

```
        string sourceString = "ABC001";
        string numberPart = sourceString.Substring(sourceString.Length - 3, 3);
        string firstPart = sourceString.Substring(0, sourceString.Length - 3);
        int newNumber = Convert.ToInt32(numberPart);
        newNumber++;
        string resut = firstPart + String.Format("{0:000}", newNumber);
```

**EDIT :** As per the comment,

If you are looking for a way to concatenate ABC and 1 in the form of ABC001, This will do

```
string firstPart="ABC";
int number=1;
string result=firstPart + String.Format("{0:000}", number);
```

Comment: Thanks, but here the input is ABC001. While what i am looking for is a way to concatenate ABC and 1 in the form of ABC001